# ¿Cómo guardo un JSON string en MySQL con PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

Tengo la siguiente cadena JSON la cual quiero almacenar su contenido en una tabla de mi base de datos en MySQL usando PHP:

```
[{
    "personal": "1001",
    "content": [{
      "language": "English",
      "words": "302",
      "approved": "yes"
    }, {
      "language": "Spanish",
      "words": "180",
      "approved": "no"
    }]
 }, {
    "personal": "1002",
    "content": [{
      "language": "Spanish",
      "words": "236",
      "approved": "yes"
    }]
}]
```

Para ello intento enviar esta cadena JSON a PHP usando AJAX, la variable `sjson` es la que almacena la cadena JSON:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   dataType: "json",
   url: "receive.php",
   data: {myData:sjson},
   success: function(data){
     console.log(data);
   },
   error: function(e){
     console.log(e.message);
   }

});
```

En mi página PHP capturo la variable:

```
<?php
    $obj = $_POST['myData'];
?>
```

Aquí es cuando estoy un poco perdido, dado que el problema es que no puedo acceder a los valores de los items `personal` y `content`, lo he intentado con un `foreach` pero recibo un resultado `undefined`

Quiero almacenar esta información en mi tabla MySQL `personal` de la siguiente manera:

```
id_personal  | language | words  | approved
--------------------------------------------
1001         | English  | 302    | yes
1001         | Spanish  | 180    | no
1002         | Spanish  | 236    | yes
```

¿Cómo puedo lograrlo?

Agradeceré su ayuda.

Comment: Lo mas conveniente es que en tu logica en PHP deserializes el JSON y mapes tu JSON a un objeto para insertar en la base de datos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes utilizar la funcion json_decode para utilizar los valores de la variable que recibes en php:

```
<?php
    $obj = json_decode($_POST['myData'], true);
    //Acceder a posicion personal
   echo $obj[0]['personal'];
   //Recorrer con foreach
  foreach($obj as $data){
      //extraer data
      $personal = $data['personal'];
      //Recorrer content 
      foreach($data['content'] as $content){
         $language = $content['language '];
         $words = $content['words'];
         $approved = $content['approved'];
        //Aca codigo para Insertar en BD 
      }

   }
?>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, he estado probando y el código no funciona, ¿Cuál es el valor de la variable `$myData`? Sigue saliendo `undefined` y no almacena nada en la base de datos

Comment: Es verdad, es la variable que guarda lo que recibiste en php, ya corregí mi respuesta, verifica y me indicas

Comment: Funciona genial, gracias!